# operator == () loops for ever

Tags: c++11, operators

see this very simple code:

```
struct A
 {   
     bool operator ==(const int &t)
     {
         return *this == t;
     }
 };
void main()
{
    A p;
    p == 2;// this code loops for ever!!! 
}
```

dose any one know why the code loops for ever ?!
actually the operator ==() calls itself recursively!
Many thanks

Comment: because `*this == t` is same as `p == 2` => call operator `==` between a struct A on left and a int on right

Comment: Hint: what happens when you execute `*this == t`?

Comment: `*this == t` equals to `this.operator==(t)`.

Comment: This post is a duplicate of [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485191/operator-loops-for-ever)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask yourself this.

What is `*this`? It's `struct A`.

So what is `*this == t` ? It is basically `A::operator==()` with argument t.

You are calling the same function.

Comment: Sometimes debug your program !